# background of summarization function in winword

Tags: nlp, linguistics, summarization

There is an automatic summarization tool in Winword. Does anybody know the background, i.e. which algorithms are used or where I can find additional background information concerning this feature?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Research does work in this area, e.g.

*[Enhancing Single-Document Summarization by Combining RankNet and Third-Party Sources](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=77563)* by Svore et al. It would be reasonable to assume that the Winword implementation is based on similar work, but I don't know the exact algorithm.